# Get column index values in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am having a gridview in asp.net, and in the table I have two columns.
Now I must show the column index value row by row on the button click in form of a alert for dllDesc and txtBoxDesc fields.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCar" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LevelID" OnRowDataBound="gvCar_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Car">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Car" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="30px" Font-Names="Georgia" MyCustomAttr="foo" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("CharName") %>'></asp:Label>


                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDesc" Width="142px" Height="35px" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" runat="server">
                         </asp:DropDownList>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxDesc" runat="server" Width="130px" Height="28px" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text=''></asp:TextBox>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView> 
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

I managed to get the value for rows(code below) but i could not find a way to show it for columns.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvCar.Rows)
    {
        string PrimaryKey = gvCar.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(PrimaryKey);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just bind it like this  on grid view don't need to do anything else

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
           </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

EDIT UPDATE 2

just add on selected index Changed event

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCar" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvCar_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and in your cs file

```
protected void gvCar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               string a  = gvCar.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text; //Write here that cell index  of index  no             
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

if you want to do that by row command then open bellow link

> [Row command example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-GridView-Row-Index-on-Button-Click-event-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

that will work for you

Comment: Can you please send me code how to return values on the button click in the c# ?

Comment: just wait two mint

Answer (score 0):

You just iterate over the columns and then you ask for the header text:`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gvCar.Columns.Count; i++)
 {
     string columnHeader = gvCar.Columns[i].HeaderText;
 }
```

**EDITED AFTER FEEDBACK:**

For the datatables I think it works like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
 {
     int colIndex = dt.Columns[i].Ordinal;
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I managed to get only column header names, but I need for every column their index number from database.

Example: 
Column 1  Columns 2
1                 3
3                 2
4                 5

Thanks for help !

Comment: Could you elaborate because as far as i know the column indexes start from 0 and go up just the same as the row indexes? So then the variable i is the index number within the for loop.

Comment: This index values are generated by a database. 
Every name that is shown in columns is bounded to the index in the database. And I need those index numbers shown.

<!-- language: c# -->
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2]{ new DataColumn("CharName", typeof(string)),                
                new DataColumn("LevelID", typeof(int))
                });
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtKar.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(dr["CharName"].ToString(), dr["LevelID"].ToString());
            }